Quadratic variation of the square of Brownian motion
Let $B_t$ be the Brownian Motion.
Find the quadratic variation of a martingale $ M_t = B_t^2-t$.
My solution:
By Ito's formula for $f(t, x) = x^2-t$, we know $$d(B_t^2-t) = 2B_t dB_t$$ thus $\langle M \rangle_t = 4 \int_0^t B_s^2 ds$.
My question is:

Is this correct?
Can I simplify the last integration?
Any other solutions? (For instance, can I calculate this directly by $$\sum_{i=1}^n (M_{t_i} - M_{t_{i-1}})^2$$ using the fact that this sum converges in probability to the quadratic variation?)


The left hand side is a number, while the right hand side is a nonconstant stochastic variable. Perhaps you meant something different and need to reformulate?

Your answer is correct. It cannot be simplified further, apart from using Itô's lemma in order to get a integral with respect to $B_t$ instead of time.

• Yes, it's correct.
• No.
• The quadratic variation of $M$ will be the same as that of $B^2$, as these two processes differ by $t$. Write
$$
(B_{t_{i}}^2 - B_{t_{i-1}}^2)^2 = (B_{t_{i}} + B_{t_{i-1}})^2(B_{t_{i}} - B_{t_{i-1}})^2.
$$
Now sum over $i$ and let $n\to\infty$. By continuity of the Brownian path, the factor $(B_{t_{i}} + B_{t_{i-1}})^2$ will be (uniformly in time) close to $(2B_{t_{i-1}})^2=4B_{t_{i-1}}^2$.
